# How are elements of a vector left-shifted in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust, memmove

Is there a safe way to left-shift elements of a vector in Rust? (`vec![1, 2, 3]` becomes `vec![3]` when left-shifted two places). I'm dealing with `Copy` types, and I don't want to pay a penalty higher than what I would with a `memmove`.

The only solution I've found is unsafe: use `memmove` directly via `ptr::copy`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would use [`Vec::drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain).

You can call it with a range of the elements you want to remove, and it'll shift them over afterwards. Example: ([playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e6451460055160a4b615df5ff5235bf3&version=stable&backtrace=0))

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];

    v.drain(0..2);

    assert_eq!(vec![3], v);
}
```

One other note:

> I'm dealing with `Copy` types, and I don't want to pay a penalty higher than what I would with a `memmove`.

Worth noting that moving is *always* a `memcpy` in Rust, so the `Copy` vs non-`Copy` distinction doesn't matter here. It'd be the same if the types weren't `Copy`.